# Where is btls-cert-sync on OSX for mono 4.8

Tags: mono

I just installed the 4.8.0 alpha version of mono to be able to make ssl requests to services that require TLS 1.2.

According to the Release Notes of the 4.8.0 there should be a tool called `btls-cert-sync`, but it is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

Use `cert-sync` going forward, `btls-cert-sync` has been removed.

> cert-sync already knew how to import into the BTLS cert store,
>   update it to always import into both stores so we don't need
>   the btls-cert-sync tool anymore.

Re: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/968c60a0f32c7a4c92568c3feda7503f99b98c94

#### btus-cert-sync:

```
>which `btls-cert-sync`
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/btls-cert-sync
```

#### `btus-cert-sync` is a shell script:

```
>cat `which btls-cert-sync`
#!/bin/sh
exec /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/4.5/btls-cert-sync.exe "$@"
```

#### Mono Version:

```
>mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.8.0 (mono-4.8.0-branch/cd26828 Fri Jan 13 14:32:29 EST 2017)
```

Comment: I have that exact monoversion, but I don't see a `btls-cert-sync` in `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/` and I'm also missing the `btls-cert-sync.exe` file under `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/4.5/`. So I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: @TomasJansson I updated my answer... (I either have an left over from a prior 4.8 alpha install and the updates are not removing it (most likely), or getting it from `Xamarin.Android`...

Comment: This is the answer a question, now I just need to figure how to run it on OSX and where the system-ca-bundle.crt is located, this should be a step in the installer :)

Comment: @TomasJansson I updated the 4.8 release notes with steps for OSX: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.8.0/#tls-12-support and removed the traces of btls-cert-sync. Note that BTLS is not the default on OSX so you need to explicitly enable it via the env var.

Comment: Great @AlexanderKöplinger!